# cannot initialize a variable of type 'BOOL' - theos

Tags: objective-c, boolean, objective-c++, theos, tweak

I am creating a tweak using theos that changes the "slide to unlock" text to a custom string

In my Tweak.xm:

```
%hook SBLockScreenView

- (void)setCustomSlideToUnlockText:(id)unlockText { 

NSString *settingsPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.motion.tweak~prefs.plist";
NSMutableDictionary *prefs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:settingsPath];
NSString *text = [prefs objectForKey:@"text"];

BOOL enabled = [prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"];

if([text isEqualToString:@""] || text == nil || ![enabled]) {
    %orig(unlockText);

}

else if ([enabled]) {

    unlockText = text;
    %orig(unlockText);
}

}

%end
```

I am returned with an error when i try make package:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')
      with an rvalue of type 'id'
BOOL enabled = [prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"];
     ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I believe [pref objectForKey:@"enabled"] will be returning an NSNumber* type.

Comment: Tim is correct, therefor change it to [[prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue]

Comment: @TimEdwards @ŃikeKamstra Thank you both i am now returned with a new error when i try make the package:

`Tweak.xm:41:58: error: expected identifier
if([text isEqualToString:@""] || text == nil || ![enabled]) {
                                                         ^
Tweak.xm:46:18: error: expected identifier
else if ([enabled]) {
                 ^`

Comment: Ill change it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First issue:

As @Tim Edwards said: 
boolean objects returned from dictionaries are returned as a NSNumber (either being a 0 or 1). So ask for the booleanvalue of the NSNumber with:

```
[ [prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"] booleanValue]
```

As far as the next error code comes to, is because you are making a faulty check with your if statement:

```
if([text isEqualToString:@""] || text == nil || ![enabled]) {
else if ([enabled]) {
```

You do not need to put booleans in brackets [] also it is better to just check your NSString only for length, rather than making 2 checks for it, so change both statements to:

```
// I am accustomed with making it <= 0 even though it's impossible. 
if(!enabled || text.length <= 0) {

else if (enabled) {
```